# Xpath giving error had invalid token

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<ns0:EnrollmentMSCSV01 xmlns:ns0="http://**************">
  <MemberRecords>
    <MemberRecord>
      <BatchSeqNo>BatchSeqNo_0</BatchSeqNo> 
      <TransactionType>TransactionType_0</TransactionType> 
      <SvcMemberID>SvcMemberID_0</SvcMemberID>
```

I have this XML structure for my schema and in my orchestration project I am trying to access the transaction Type and perform some steps.
I am using this XPath expression to retrieve the transaction type. But gettting invalid token error.

```
/*[local-name()='EnrollmentSV01' and namespace-uri()='http://intervalintl.com/shell']
 /*[local-name()='MemberRecords' and namespace-uri()='']
 /*[local-name()='MemberRecord' and namespace-uri()='']
 /*[local-name()='TransactionType' and namespace-uri()='']
```

Please let me know the right XPath to retrieve `TransactionType`

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message, and what language or tool are you using?  At first glance I can't see anything invalid about that XPath expression (though it is rather longer than it needs to be as the non-namespaced elements could simply be referred to as `MemberRecords/MemberRecord/TransactionType`).

Comment: I second Ian. Also, If you replace your URI in the XML, it might have been a good idea to do the same in your XPath...

Comment: Of course, as it stands the expression won't match anything, because you've got `EnrollmentSV01` in the XPath and `EnrollmentMSCSV01` in the document, but it shouldn't cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest XPath expression to retrieve the TransactionType element is

```
//TransactionType
```

but I don't know why you are getting an error with the expression you are using.